# Error : bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), for UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitextfield, uialertview

****bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool),**** 0x4c7a7e0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

I m getting an above error when i do this,

[alertForSavingText dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:ALERT_CANCEL animated:YES];

This is my custom alert with textField inside. Error comes only when I switch the application from background to foreground also it occurs when there is some text present in custom alert textField & keyboard is also visible.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the current thread is main thread. If it is main thread, dismiss it as you have given. Else, if it is secondary thread, dismiss the alert view in main thread by calling `performSelectorInMainThread:...` method